# reading 2D array behavior issue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Test Cases:

```
(6, [1,3,2,6,1,2]) returns (pairs / 2) = 5
```

It does get the answer the thing is that is doing more than it needs to, It is possible just add some validation to know when he is adding same reversed index but it will only give it more to do. am looking to remove the unneeded work. can it be more reliable?

```
function returnOcurrences(k,ar){
    debugger;
    const letters = [new Set(ar)];
    let pairs = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        for (let ii = 0; ii < ar.length; ii++) {
            let a = ar[i] + ar[ii];
            if (i != ii) {
                if (a >= k) {
                    pairs += (a % k == 0) ? 1 : 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return pairs/2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I assume you want to do is prevent the algorithm from checking e.g. `ar[1] + ar[2]`, then `ar[2] + ar[1]` again.

To solve this, consider starting your inner loop from `i + 1` and not from 0. This prevents the mentioned scenario from happening, and also prevents the algorithm from summing an element with itself (e.g. `ar[0] + ar[0]`). So no need to check anymore if `i` is equal to `ii`.

Why so? Assume the first iteration of the outer loop. You are checking the sum of ar[0] with `ar[1]`, then with `ar[2]`, `ar[3]`, and so on.

On the second iteration of the outer loop, you are checking sums of `ar[1]` with other elements of the array. However, you already checked `ar[0]` + `ar[1]` in the previous iteration. So you start with `ar[1]` + `ar[2]`, where `ii = i + 1 = 2`.

So the code becomes:

```
function returnOcurrences(k,ar){
    const letters = [new Set(ar)]; //I don't see the purpose of this variable but okay
    var pairs = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        for (var ii = i + 1; ii < ar.length; ii++) {
            var a = ar[i] + ar[ii];
                if (a >= k) {
                    pairs += (a % k == 0) ? 1 : 0
                }
        }
    }
    return pairs/2;
}
```

Hope this helps!